# How to use flow type with VS Code and WSL?

Tags: flowtype, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying out Windows Subsystem for Linux(WSL) in Windows 10. So far it has worked great and I have node, git and VS code set up successfully without much problem.

But I have been unable to get flow working with VS Code. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a few hours tinkering with the setup, I got it working. Here's what I did.

- It turns out flow is officially supported on Windows.[Mentioned on this blog post](https://flow.org/blog/2016/08/01/Windows-Support/).
- I downloaded `flow-win64-vx.xx.x.zip` from the [Github release page.](https://github.com/facebook/flow/releases)
- Save the `flow.exe` file from the zip anywhere you like.
- Tell the flow extension the path to the executable. In VS Code settings add `flow.pathToFlow: "C:\\Users\\Shouvik\\flow\\flow.exe"`.
- Restart VS Code, and it should be working now.

Comment: Just install it via npm (as recomended on official GitHub page) and you're good to go